# egit can not push to TFS 2015

Tags: git, ssh, tfs

I'm trying to push to a git repository hosted on TFS 2015 using eclipse git plugin (egit).

After a timeout-period of 5 minutes the client fails with one of these messages

> Can't connect to any repository: ssh://tfs.buenting.de:22/tfs/BIT/ZP/_git/dummy.hello-world (ssh://tfs.buenting.de:22/tfs/BIT/ZP/_git/dummy.hello-world: error occurred during unpacking on the remote end: error Wait for data timeout elapsed. OnData event failed to be raised within expected time.)

or

> Short read of block.

Same Problem on Windows and Linux, tested with egit versions 4.4.0.201606070830, 4.6.1.201703071140, 4.8.0.201706111038 and 4.9.0.201710071750 (latest on oxygen).

Pushing from the same repository with other git clients works fine: git-bash on Windows (1.9.5.msysgit.0), git on Linux (versions 1.9.1, 2.11.0).

Pushing to TFS 2017 with egit also works fine.

Questions:

- does anyone work successfully with egit and TFS 2015?

  How do we get this combination to work?

For some reason, we are not able to switch to TFS 2017 in production in the near future.

Also using git on TFS over http will be no solution, because we don't want to store credentials in eclipse.

Comment: Have you tried other clients? I mean a clean client, do they have the same issue?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT: what do you mean with "clean"? As I mentioned in my question I tried with git-bash on Windows and "default"-git on linux without any problems with the same repository.

Comment: I mean a new environemnet. make sure no other third components caused that. Based on your description,seems it's the egit issue.  As a workaround you can use other git clients to push to TFS 2015.